# How to use custom Django Authentication with it's rest TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I am using a third party Authentication (Firebase Auth)(Facebook && Google) with my Django Application.

I did set up some rest endpoints that need authentication to post some content.

I will very well like to use the Django Rest Framework Token Authentication. However, this requires that I have to pass a username & password in other to get the token.

Since I am using Firebase(Facebook and Google), users are not asked to set any password.
Here is my CustomUser model.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=191, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="", blank=True)
```

Is there any workaround or ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without a hint about your user model, but Django Rest Framework Token doesn't require a password. You can create a token by providing user only (which doesn't have to be django's auth user model).

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

To use Django's user model without a password, you can use `user.set_unusable_password()` right after creating the user object.

Comment: Thank you. I added some code for the CustomUser, please do take a look.